# Spark: forcing each task on a seperate executor

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

Suppose we have a SparkDataFrame of 20 rows. I'm applying a pyspark UDF on each row that performs some expensive calculation.

```py
def expensive_python_function(df, a, b) -> pd.DataFrame:
    return ...

def create_udf(a: Broadcast, b: Broadcast, func: Broadcast) -> Callable:
    def my_udf(df: pd.DataFrame) -> pd.DataFrame:
        result = func.value(df, a.value, b.value)
        result["timestamp"] = datetime.datetime.now()
        return result
    return my_udf

broadcast_func = sparkContext.broadcast(expensive_python_function)
broadcast_a = sparkContext.broadcast(a)
broadcast_b = sparkContext.broadcast(b)

result = sdf.groupby(*groups).applyInPandas(
      create_udf(broadcast_a, broadcast_b, broadcast_func), 
      schema=schema
)

result.show()
```

To clarify, each unique group in the groupby will result in a dataframe of one row.

The variables a and b are used by each executor and are the same for all of them. I am accessing the variables in `my_udf` using `broadcast_a.value`.

**Problem**

This operation results in 2 partitions and thus 2 tasks. Both tasks are executed on a single (the same) executor. Obviously that is not what I want, I would like to have each task run on a seperate executor in parrallel.

**What I tried**

I repartitioned the dataframe into 20 partitions and used persist the cache it in memory.

```py
sdf = sdf.repartition(20).persist()


result = sdf.groupby(*groups).applyInPandas(
      create_udf(broadcast_a, broadcast_b, broadcast_func), 
      schema=schema
)

result.show()
```

This indeed gives me 20 partitions and 20 tasks to be completed. However, from the 10 executors only 1 is still active.

[image]

I tried:

- setting spark.executor.cores explictly to 1
- setting spark.sql.shuffle.partitions to 20

I also noticed that each executor does contain rdd block, that puzzles me as well?

**Question**

It seems to me like the spark driver is deciding for me that all jobs can be run on one executor, which makes sense from a big data point of view. I realize that Spark is not exactly intended for my use-case, I'm testing if and what kind of speedup I can achieve as oppossed to using something like python `multiprocessing`.

Is it possible to force each task to be run on a seperate executor, regardless of the size of the data or the nature of the task?

I'm using Python 3.9 and Spark 3.2.1

Comment: If your udf has some code that needs the complete dataset, like calculating cumulative aggregation, you will have to broadcast and combine the results. For this spark simply sends the data to a single executor. But you can share the udf so the community can help you point out the issues.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, my udf only needs one row (group) of the dataset to complete it's task. Thus, all tasks are completely independent (i.e. I could also run them using `multiprocessing`).

Comment: @glory9211, Sorry, I just realized; do you mean I also need to broadcast if the udf uses variables that are shared accross all executors? I'll try that.

Comment: Would it be possible to add your `spark-submit` to the question?

Comment: @JoepAtol yes. that would be the case. Spark has good docs on it.
Also the more you share about your udf the more help you will get. Code will be better but you can share sudo steps if you are shy ;)

Comment: @glory9211 updated the question with your remarks implemented. I can share my_udf but it's quite large. Hope this update helps, I'll create a smaller example version that covers the issues today. Thank for your help!

Comment: @VikramsinhShinde I can, there are a lot of settings so the whole thing is probably not helpful. Any settings you are especially interested in?

Comment: Want to have a look at these values - `spark.default.parallelism, spark.cores.max, num-executors, executor-cores`.

Comment: @VikramsinhShinde I don't change, `spark.default.parallelism`, `spark.cores.max`. `num-executors` = 10, `executor-cores` = 1

Comment: @glory9211 updated the question, with some more background on the udf. Does this help?

Comment: any particular reason for using pandas df ? You can store the groupedData df after applying any agg like count, max, then use df.rdd.getNumPartitions to see how many partitions are there. If it is 1, increase the num of partitions

Comment: Well, it's a Pandas UDF right? So it should expect a pandas dataframe. I did repartition the SparkDataFrame just before `groupby` and it does have 20 partitions. It also shows 20 tasks in SparkUI. It's just executing them one at a time instead of in parallel.

Answer (score 1):

So, the solution lied in not using the DataFrame API. Working with RDD's seems to give you much more control.

```py
params = [(1,2), (3,4), (5,6)]

@dataclass
class Task:
   func: Callable
   a: int
   b: int

def run_task(task: Task):
    return task.func(task.a, task.b)

data = spark.parallelize(
   [Task(expensive_python_function, a, b) for a, b in params],
   len(params)]
)

result = data.map(run_task)
```

It will return an RDD, so you need to convert to DataFrame. Or use `collect()` to collect to get the result.

To be sure I also set `spark.default.parallelism = str(len(params))` and I set `spark.executor.instances = str(len(params))`. I believe the parallelism setting should not be necessary as you are basically passing that in `spark.parallelize` as well.

Hope it helps someone!